# each class distribution in a classification problem

Tags: classification

Can we tell that the distribution of each class differs and the distribution of dataset is the combination of the classes distribution?

What can we infer about the class distribution?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we tell that the distribution of each class differs and the distribution of dataset is the combination of the classes distribution?

No, because the class is the variable and each particular class is a specific value for this variable. A value doesn't have a distribution, only a variable has a distribution. A value has a probability.

> What can we infer about the class distribution?

Depends what you're looking for. A common observation about the class distribution is its level of imbalance.

Comment: The class may not have distribution but the samples that fall within the class has a distribution. Am I right ?

Comment: @SSVarshini yes but then you're not talking about the class distribution, you're talking about some different variables, for example the features.